# Cytoscape.js : fixedNodeConstraint when collapsing or expanding compound nodes

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I'm looking for a way to apply constraints for fixed nodes when collapsing or expanding compound nodes with Fcose layout (last version of cytoscape on May 2022).
I applied it the following:

```
api.expand(cy.$id(selection), options)
```

with

```
option ={
name:'fcose',
quality:"default",
animate:true,
animationDuration:1000,
animationEasing;'ease-out',
fit:'true',
step:"all",
fixedNodeConstraint:[{"nodeId":"id1, "position":{"x":10, "y":50}},... ]
}
```

The constraint on fixed node seems then not to apply, but it could not be the appropriate way for such constraints applying.

Any experience and ideas on the way to proceed?